# Generic name for distinguishable pointers

Tags: pointers, generics, fortran

Is it possible to use the same generic name for two pointers of different type? The following of course doesn't work, but it should make clear what I mean:

```
real(4), pointer :: s_p
real(8), pointer :: d_p
generic :: p => s_p,d_p
```

For procdures these things can be done with interfaces defining destinguishable procedures as `module procedure` and for type bound procedures there exists the `generic` type that is used similar to the given example. So I wonder if something like this exists for pointers too.

I'd like to mention that unlimited polymorphic pointers (`class(*)`) are probably not what I want, since I'm trying to generalize an existing library to double precision input, thus I'd have a lot more work in implementing the `select type` blocks than just defining two pointers everywhere.

EDIT:

It is of course possible to associate the same pointer with variables of different type/kind. Just some examples:

```
program test

   implicit none
   real(4),target :: a
   real(8),target :: b
   class(*),pointer :: p

   a=2e0
   b=3d0

   p=>a
   call printer(p)
   a=a+4e0
   call printer(p)
   p=>b
   call printer(p)

   associate (u=>a)       ! for me it's still a miracle why this even works
      print*,u
      a=a+3e0
      print*,u
   end associate
   associate (u=>b)
      print*,u
   end associate

contains

   subroutine printer(p)

      class(*),pointer :: p

      select type (p) 
      type is (real(4))
         p=p+2d0              ! even the wrong 2d0 gets converted correctly
         print*,p
      type is (real(8))
         print*,p
      end select

   end subroutine

end program
```

My problem with this solution is that I would have to implement `select type` blocks everywhere in the library where the pointer is used. (At the moment I only know that it's many places.)

So the main problem is that the unlimited polymorphic pointer (p in the example) stays polymorphic unless it is used inside a `select type` environement. This is of course necessary, since the pointer could be everything. So the actual question is: Is there a possibility to tell the polymorphic pointer in advance: You can only be either this or that (e.g real(4) or real(8)) and depening on what it is associated to, it knows what it is?

The answer is probably no, but at the moment I don't really see, in which situtation the compliler might have problems to distinguish between types/kinds.

Comment: Did you consider using 'include's? I think some-one called this "Poor-man's templates"... [Looking for the reference]

Comment: Do you mean something like `include [file_name]`? No I didn't, and at the moment I don't see how this would help me?!

Comment: With your comment below my answer I am confused what your actual question is. Maybe you should expand your question about what the current situation is, and what you want to achieve. A single pointer that can be pointed to different kind of floats does not exist, see my answer.

Comment: But this is what I would like to have. See my updated question. I hope it gets more clear now.

Comment: `associate` is NOT associating a variable with a pointer, it is just associating it with a different *(associate-)name*, which is however not a pointer. You cannot use it as a pointer.

Comment: @HPM: I'm confused about what `u` is for the compiler, it's not even defined.

Comment: @Vladimir F: Thanks, but I would highly appreciat a comment on 'however', since at least inside the `associate` block it seems to behave like a pointer. ... just for my understanding.

Comment: It is just a different name, not a pointer. Pointer is something you can point at different targets. The *associate-name* is just an alias name fio some expression or variable.

Comment: Thanks you, indeed that's a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  A data pointer is a variable.  You cannot have two different variables with the same name accessible in the same scope.

If you hypothetically could... in many cases the compiler would have no way of knowing which variable you meant when that common name appeared.

The situation for generic procedure names is different - the compiler can resolve which specific procedure is relevant when a generic procedure name is referenced by examining the number, types, kinds and ranks of the arguments in the procedure reference.  The rules of the language ensure that there can only be at most one such matching specific procedure, and that generic procedure names do not appear in contexts where the ability to resolve the relevant specific procedure is not possible.

Comment: I have no clue about how the compiler works in detail, but I don't really see, in which specific case, the compiler might have problems with what I had in mind. I still believe you are right, anyway I updated my question, to make clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Clause C714 (R733) from the Fortran 2008 Standard states:

> If data-target is not unlimited polymorphic, data-pointer-object
>   shall be type compatible (4.3.1.3) with it and the **corresponding kind
>   type parameters shall be equal.**

You could, however, put the corresponding code in its own file, and include it with a different kind variable in place:

common.inc.F90:

```
real(KINDVAR), pointer :: p

contains

function fun1(x) result(res)
  real(KINDVAR) :: x, res
  ! ...
end function
```

module_double.F90:

```
module test_double
  use,intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env, only: REAL64
  integer,parameter :: KINDVAR = REAL64

  include 'common.inc.F90'
end module
```

module_single.F90:

```
module test_single
  use,intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env, only: REAL32
  integer,parameter :: KINDVAR = REAL32

  include 'common.inc.F90'
end module
```

Then you can include the different modules, and even rename the subroutines on-the-fly:

```
use test_single only: fun1_sgl => fun1, p_sgl => p
use test_double only: fun1_dbl => fun1, p_dbl => p
```

This is called "Poor man's templates" and was published [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=274108).

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer, but I think that's not really what I need. The pointer is defined inside a module and used at many places, that I don't necessarily know.

Comment: Well, this is just an example... Instead of functions, you could also `use` pointers with a certain `kind`... I updated the answer to reflect that.